# loading Rcpp through JGR Console

Tags: r, rcpp

I have created a package that depends on Rcpp and RcppArmadillo. My package operates smoothly without a problem on the R console. However, when I try to loaded it from JGR console it reports the following error

```
Error: package 'Rcpp' 0.9.9 is loaded, but >= 0.9.10 is required by 'RcppArmadillo'
```

Actually, I have updated Rcpp to version 0.9.10 on my machine. In the R console you can see that

```
sessionInfo()
attached base packages:
[1] compiler  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] prophecy_2.1         XLConnect_0.1-9      XLConnectJars_0.1-4  rJava_0.9-3          RcppArmadillo_0.2.36 Rcpp_0.9.10
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This has *nothing* to do with Rcpp and is all about your R patch:

- Print the result of `.libPaths()`
- Look at the result of `library()`
- Do that both on the console and with JGR. You probably have different outcomes.
- Delete the old Rcpp 0.9.9 in the path added by JGR.

Comment: I knew the problem is not related to Rcpp. A comparison of .libPaths() in the R console and JGR console solved the problem. I found that JGR using the desktop library, which I was not aware of. 
In the R console
C:\Users\samuel\Documents\R\win-library\2.14
In the JGR console
C:\Users\samuel\Desktop\R\win-library\2.14
Thanks Dirk for the advice, now I can proceed to build GUI.

Comment: If the answer helped, it would now be common to a) accept it by clicking on the tick mark, and b) possibly also 'up-vote' it by clicking on the triangle.